# In what countries are tea towels available as souvenirs?

Tags: countries, souvenirs

In which countries are tea towels available as souvenirs? So far, I haven't seen this as a thing in Japan, and I want to know if this is the case in other countries, such as South Korea.

Is it countries that *do* have tea towels available as souvenirs that are in the minority?

Comment: This was inspired by a recent English.SE question.

Comment: Isn't this like....most countries?  Seems massively broad, and you're basically asking for a list.  And a quick google search for japanese tea towel souvenir certainly shows that they do exist for Japan as well.

Comment: I would've thought it's just an Aussie thing, perhaps also in New Zealand and England, and if so then other English-y Commonwealth countries. This is a very silly question - but I like it (-:

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I think you should include a photo or two to show people what you mean, otherwise they'll just think you'd buy any plain regular tea towel from a supermarket rather than ones especially made to be souvenirs as everybody's grandmother has in Australia.

Comment: My parents have one from like Turkey, I've seen them in South America, Japan and more.  I'd be surprised more to see countries that *don't* sell them as souvenirs.

Comment: voted to close - way too broad.

Comment: Here's the English SE question referred to, linking to an answer claiming they're not a thing in the USA. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/209924

Comment: [Definitely a thing in USA](https://www.etsy.com/market/souvenir_linens) - link shows an Alaskan one, a Cape Cod Massachusetts one...